# DocuSign API Integration in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8, docusignapi, php-8, docusign-sdk

Is it necessary to have an account of docusign for the client who is going to sign the document?

Comment: No, it is not necessary for the signer to have a DocuSign account in order to sign a document. DocuSign provides the option for signers to sign documents as a guest, without the need for an account.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part - no
Signers don't need to have an account with DocuSign.
You do have to have an account for the "sender" which is the account authenticate via the API and used to obtain an access token which is then used to make the API call that generates the envelope.

Comment: But, I want clarification that..in this case, is signer receive mail? Beacause in my case only sender received the mail from docusign.

Comment: If you use remote signing - signers receive email, and sign asynchronously from their email wherever they are.
If you use embedded signing - signers do NOT receive email and they sign inside your app.

Comment: Can you please provide me the documentation for embedded signing and remote signing?

Comment: My requirement is to request remote signing  by email in laravel.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/